# Oracle database SqlPlus - how to switch instance

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I am totally new to oracle.

I have two instances on one oracle server. When I am connecting to the server via sqlplus, by default it opens a connection to instance X but I need to connect to instance Y.

How can I do that?

Comment: Try `connect username/password@servicename` (obviously substituting your actual credentials).

Answer (score 0):

try this please :

Ensure that the environment variables ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID are set properly. The commands to use to set these environment variables depend on the shell you use to interface with the operating system. For example:

```
(bash or ksh) export ORACLE_SID=orcl --this is your X or your Y

(csh or tcsh) setenv ORACLE_SID orcl
```

I got this from here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-EC18C4A6-3BA5-4C14-9D76-B0DD62FEFFF2.htm#ADMQS12369

And then you should try to connect as `sqlplus / as sysdba`.